# Objects that represent trees

Tags: c#, .net, tree, binary-tree

Are there any objects in C# (or in .net) that represents a binary tree (or for curiosity) and n-ary tree?

I am not talking about presentation tree controls, but as model objects.

If not, are there any good external implementations?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [NGenerics](https://github.com/ngenerics/ngenerics) project is a awesome collection of data structures and algorithms including a [Binary Tree](https://github.com/ngenerics/ngenerics/wiki/BinaryTree).

```
public class BinaryTree<T> : IVisitableCollection<T>, ITree<T>
{
  // Methods
  public void Add(BinaryTree<T> subtree);
  public virtual void breadthFirstTraversal(IVisitor<T> visitor);
  public virtual void 
         DepthFirstTraversal(OrderedVisitor<T> orderedVisitor);
  public BinaryTree<T> GetChild(int index);
  public bool Remove(BinaryTree<T> child);
  public virtual void RemoveLeft();
  public virtual void RemoveRight();

  // ...

  // Properties
  public virtual T Data { get; set; }
  public int Degree { get; }
  public virtual int Height { get; }
  public virtual bool IsLeafNode { get; }
  public BinaryTree<T> this[int i] { get; }
  public virtual BinaryTree<T> Left { get; set; }
  public virtual BinaryTree<T> Right { get; set; }
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting  :) I had never heard of RedBlackTree or the SplayTree.

Comment: No problem, in that case I would highly recommend a datastructure and algorithm book like http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0201000237?ie=UTF8&tag=lethologicane-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0201000237

Answer (score 8):

My attempt at a simple (non-balancing) binary search tree.

```
public sealed class BinarySearchTree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
   private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;
   public BinaryTreeNode<T> Root { get; private set; }

   public BinarySearchTree()
   {    
   }

   public BinarySearchTree(IEnumerable<T> collection) : 
       this(collection, Comparer<T>.Default)
   {
   }

   public BinarySearchTree(IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer)
   {
       if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
       if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");

       _comparer = comparer;
       foreach (var item in collection)
           Add(item);
   }

   public BinarySearchTree(BinaryTreeNode<T> root)
   {
       Root = root;
   }

   public void Add(T val)   
   {    
       var newNode = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(val);
       if (Root == null)
       {
           Root = newNode;
           return;
       }

       Add(Root, newNode);  
   }

   void Add(BinaryTreeNode<T> root, BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
   {
       if (_comparer.Compare(node.Value, root.Value) <= 0)
       {
           if (root.Left == null)
               root.Left = node;
           else
               Add(root.Left, node);
       }
       else //node.Value > root.Value
       {
           if (root.Right == null)
               root.Right = node;
           else
               Add(root.Right, node);   
       }
   }

   public bool Contains(T val)
   {
       return Contains(Root, val);
   }

   bool Contains(BinaryTreeNode<T> node, T val)
   {
       if (node == null) 
           return false;

       var comparison = _comparer.Compare(val, node.Value);
       if (comparison == 0) //val = node.value
           return true;
       else if (comparison < 0) //val < node.Value
           return Contains(node.Left, val);
       else //val > node.Value
           return Contains(node.Right, val);
   }

   public T GetMinimum()
   {
       if (Root == null)
           return default(T);

       var node = Root;
       while (node.Left != null)
           node = node.Left;

       return node.Value;       
   }

   public T GetMaximum()
   {
       if (Root == null)
           return default(T);

       var node = Root;
       while (node.Right != null)
           node = node.Right;

       return node.Value;       
   }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
       return new BinaryTreeEnumerator<T>(Root);
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
       return GetEnumerator();
   }
}

public sealed class BinaryTreeNode<T>
{
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left {get; set;}
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Right {get; set;}      
    public T Value {get; private set;}

    public BinaryTreeNode(T val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }
}

public sealed class BinaryTreeEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private Stack<BinaryTreeNode<T>> _stack = new Stack<BinaryTreeNode<T>>();
    public T Current { get; private set; }

    public BinaryTreeEnumerator(BinaryTreeNode<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return; //empty root = Enumerable.Empty<T>()

        PushLeftBranch(root);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _stack = null; //help GC
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_stack.Count == 0)
            return false;

        var node = _stack.Pop();
        Current = node.Value;

        if (node.Right != null)
            PushLeftBranch(node.Right);

        return true;
    }

    private void PushLeftBranch(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
    {
        while (node != null)
        {
            _stack.Push(node);
            node = node.Left;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _stack.Clear();
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be extremely useful if it implemented the IEnumerable interface such that it becomes compatible with LINQ and data structure conversion

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of one in the framework, but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BinarySearchTree.aspx) is one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095822/Choosing-the-Right-Collection) says that [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) are both based on trees.