# Is there a built-in Binary Search Tree in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, binary-tree

Is there a built-in binary search tree in .NET 4.0, or do I need to build this abstract data type from scratch?

## Edit

This is about the binary search tree specifically, and not abstract data type "trees" in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects that represent trees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806511/objects-that-represent-trees)

Comment: Yeah and you knew that six years ago too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3262982/53236 :P

Comment: @RobertMacLean ... and since then, .NET have evolved and last year I learnt the real answer is YES http://stackoverflow.com/a/34083290/286244 :)

Comment: Then based on the fact that StackOverflow is editable, shouldn't someone come back and edit these or close these? Basically by leaving an old incorrect/incomplete answer aren't we hurting future hunters of knowledge?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. Unfortunately the answers here did not suit my needs. E.g. the SortedSet<T> _uses_ a binary search tree (BST) but it is not a BST because it does not expose the classical BST methods and properties. For this reason I have implemented a [library](https://github.com/m31coding/M31.BinarySearchTrees) from scratch.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think the [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) class in `System.Collections.Generic` is what you're looking for.

From [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SortedSet_T__Collection.aspx):

> It is implemented using a
>   **self-balancing red-black tree** that
>   gives a performance complexity of
>   **O(log n)** for insert, delete, and
>   lookup. It is used to keep the
>   elements in sorted order, to get the
>   subset of elements in a particular
>   range, or to get the **Min** or **Max**
>   element of the set.

Source code https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs

Comment: A Red-Black Tree is really a specialized kind of Binary Search Tree. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Unfortunatly this class doesn't provide many useful methods of classic Binary Search Tree, e. g. lower_bound (which is implemented in `std::set` in C++). Beware of GetViewBetween method. Unexpectedly it has [linear running time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850975/why-sortedsett-getviewbetween-isnt-olog-n)

Comment: This answer is wrong. SortedSet<T> is not a BST. The insert and delete have a time-complexity of O(n).

Comment: SortedSet is a Binary Search Tree. dotnet opensource code is available on github for reference.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs

Comment: This uses binary search on list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Should `SortedSet.First()` return the root node of the BST? If not, is it returning the first item that was added? Or the one that was added last?

Answer (score 24):

Five years after I asked the question I realized that there is indeed a built in Binary Search Tree in .NET 4.0. It has probably been added later on, and works as expected. It self-balances (traversing) after each insert which decrease performance on adding a large range of items.

The **[`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.100).aspx)** Class has the following remarks:

> The SortedDictionary generic class is a binary search tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the dictionary. In this respect, it is similar to the SortedList generic class. The two classes have similar object models, and both have O(log n) retrieval.

Comment: Why would you need a key (perhaps your model required it)?  Doesn't SortedSet<T> cover this already (but without the key)?

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot That's why I accepted the answer SortedSet<T> ;-)

Answer (score 11):

No, .NET does not contain a [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). It does contain a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) which is a specialized kind of Binary Search Tree in which each node is painted red or black and there are certain rules using these colours which keep the tree balanced and allows the tree to guarantee **O(logn)** search times. A standard Binary Search Tree cannot guarantee these search times.

The class is called a [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) and was introduced in .NET 4.0. You can look at it's source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs). Here is an example of it's use:

```
// Created sorted set of strings.
var set = new SortedSet<string>();

// Add three elements.
set.Add("net");
set.Add("net");  // Duplicate elements are ignored.
set.Add("dot");
set.Add("rehan");

// Remove an element.
set.Remove("rehan");

// Print elements in set.
foreach (var value in set)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

// Output is in alphabetical order:
// dot
// net
```

Answer (score 4):

The C5 collections library (see http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) includes `TreeDictionary<>` classes with balanced red-black binary trees.  Note: I have not used this library yet, as the work I do needs nothing more that the standard .NET collections.

Comment: Nice one. Red-Black trees are a little different than ordinary BinarySearchTrees, but still a very nice algorithm! I'll bookmark that link right away, and save it on my XMarks account :)
Thanx Dr Herbie.

Answer (score 2):

Thanx to **herzmeister der welten**, I now know there are! I tried it and it really worked!

```
namespace Tree
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SortedSet<int> binTree = new SortedSet<int>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Insert(int no)
        {
            binTree.Add(no);
        }

        private void Print()
        {
            foreach (int i in binTree)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", i);
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Insert(Int32.Parse(tbxValue.Text));
            tbxValue.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean with 'tree', but you can do binary searchs on the List class.

```
public int BinarySearch( T item );
public int BinarySearch( T item, IComparer<T> comparer );
public int BinarySearch( int index, int count, T item, IComparer<T> comparer );
```